# Oracle Trigger PLS 00103

Tags: oracle

I am a novice in PL/SQL and DB objects. I have written an after insert trigger based on condition but I am getting PLS 00103 error encountered ;. Please help.

Below is my trigger script,

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger1 AFTER INSERT
    ON Table1
   FOR EACH ROW
 when (new.upper(Table1.column1)='ABC')
Declare
  ITEM_CODE table2.ITEM_CODE%TYPE;
BEGIN
  ITEM_CODE := :new.ITEM_CODE;

  INSERT INTO table2( PK,ITEM_CODE,EVENT_NUMBER)
    VALUES(EVENT_NUMBER_SEQ.NEXTVAL, ITEM_CODE,EVENT_NUMBER_SEQ.NEXTVAL);        
END;
```

I am executing this script through Toad.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `(new.upper(Table1.column1)='ABC')` should be `upper(new.column1) - 'ABC'`

Answer (score 1):

problem is here: `when (new.upper(Table1.column1)='ABC')` should be `(when upper(new.column1) ='ABC')` 
Also you don't need declare variable only to assign value. Just use value directly.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger1 AFTER INSERT
    ON Table1
   FOR EACH ROW
when (upper(new.column1) ='ABC')`
BEGIN
--  IF (upper(:new..column1) ='ABC') THEN
  INSERT INTO table2( PK,ITEM_CODE,EVENT_NUMBER)
    VALUES(EVENT_NUMBER_SEQ.NEXTVAL, :new.ITEM_CODE,EVENT_NUMBER_SEQ.NEXTVAL);   
--END IF;     
END;
```

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov Yes, I did IF first and copied to when. Removed semicolon from `when` clause.